# Apache storm stuck on loading summary

Tags: apache-storm

I ran zookeeper and ran nimbus, supervisor and ui however, the UI is stuck on loading summary
[That what is looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5AON.png)

This is my storm.yaml

```
storm.local.dir: "/Users/ps12/apache-storm-2.3.0"
nimbus.host: "127.0.0.1" # for nimbus
nimbus.seeds: ["localhost"]
supervisor.slots.ports:
 - 6700  
 - 6701
 - 6702
 - 6703
```

and this is my JPS

```
14469 Jps
58823 JarBootstrapMain
6089 UIServer
11083 UIServer
6157 UIServer
71825 RunJar
61009 JarBootstrapMain
11473 QuorumPeerMain
6930 UIServer
12114 Nimbus
53715 NodeManager
70485 RunJar
6421 UIServer
72151 RunJar
6871 UIServer
70555 JarBootstrapMain
44255 SparkSubmit
75041 RunJar
74592 RunJar
59233 JarBootstrapMain
12003 UIServer
53414 SecondaryNameNode
7271 UIServer
61673 JarBootstrapMain
75307 RunJar
71978 RunJar
53611 ResourceManager
53164 NameNode
8044 UIServer
98412 RunJar
6765 UIServer
74351 RunJar
72494 RunJar
11505 ZooKeeperMain
12273 Supervisor
66613 JarBootstrapMain
76020 RunJar
68087 JarBootstrapMain
72886 RunJar
6841 UIServer
6397 UIServer
6653 UIServer
13758 UIServer
46398 SparkSubmit
44799 SparkSubmit
```

What is wrong ??

I tried many things but it did not work too

Comment: It looks like the UIServer is running multiple times in parallel - this you probably do not want to. Try to kill all UIs at first and start a new one. Then please look in to your log-files (nimbus.log) and check whats going on there.

Comment: Supervisors [] are blacklisted. this what happen in the log file